# How to read a SSIS package

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

I am testing an open source software which uses the SQL SERVER 2014 database and .NET Framework 3.5.

My job is identifying whether it is possible to transfer the platform to Linux server and change some functions in the software. But I got stuck when came across these SSIS things.....

I have 5 '.dtsx' files scheduled as jobs and each of them contains thousands of lines (I think the package deals with requesting remote web service, manipulating data those things...). I am quite confusing what exactly going on inside the package. Is there a way to visualize the package?  What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're right, they're not intended to normally be viewed as files. If you have Visual Studio to hand, you can install SQL Server Data Tools which will allow you to open the files and take a look. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: @Rich Thanks, man!  I just tried it. But I still wonder if I can have a better view to look into the package?

Comment: Better than what? They should open visually. If they don't, make a new SSIS project in SSDT/Visual Studio, and then add existing files to add them. This should convert them to an appropriate version if possible and show them visually.

Comment: I thought there would be some tools to explain the package.. then I realised there are not! LOL thanks for your help!

Comment: you can try this http://ssisdocumenter.com/Preview.aspx